# How would I turn this array of letters, with choices, into a list of possible words?

Tags: python

```
7h47 --> should be 'that' in 1337speak
[['j', 't'], ['h'], ['a', 'h'], ['j', 't']]
```

So the output should be: `possible_words = [jhaj, jhat, jhhj, jhht, thaj, that, thhj, thht]`, just having trouble getting to this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of these lists.

Happily, Python does the hard work for you and everything you need is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
import itertools

letters = [['j', 't'], ['h'], ['a', 'h'], ['j', 't']]
words = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*letters)]
```

And you get:

```py
['jhaj', 'jhat', 'jhhj', 'jhht', 'thaj', 'that', 'thhj', 'thht']
```

**In more details**, `itertools.product` returns an iterator that generates all possible combinations of the parameters (a list of letters). Then we iterate over these combinations within a list comprehension and use `join` to get a word from each list of "chars" (`str` of length 1 in Python).

Answer (score 2):

If you're a recursion fan, here's an approach using generators:

```py
def combine(combinations, prefix=''):
    head, *tail = combinations

    # If it's the last word from the combinations
    if not tail:
        # Yield the full word using the head as suffixes
        for letter in head:
            yield prefix + letter
    else:
        # Yield from the tail combinations using the head as suffixes
        for letter in head:
            yield from combine(tail, prefix + letter)    

print(list(combine([['j', 't'], ['h'], ['a', 'h'], ['j', 't']])))
# ['jhaj', 'jhat', 'jhhj', 'jhht', 'thaj', 'that', 'thhj', 'thht']
```